# How to use $event.target to make changes to view

Tags: angular

I know I should use binding. But I need some flexibility here. 
Given a long list of records, I want to do something on each record by clicking a button of each record, when it finishes, I just want to change the record status.

On each record, I can "do(record, $event)". I can see I have `$event.target` which is the button of my click. It's great. Because after I'm done. I want to replace the button with a "Done".

How to achieve that?

Comment: after i am done, how do you know it is done

Comment: You want to change the button text or remove the button and show some text?

Comment: `do(record) { someWork(); record.done = true; }`. And in the view: `<button *ngIf="!record.done" (click)="do(record)">DO</button><span *ngIf="record.done">Done</span>`

Comment: don't want to touch the record itself. Done when some async job finished then I can do something. Replace button with "done" text.

Comment: Then wrap your records into objects that you can modify, and which have a done flag, and the record themselves. Or maintain an association between records and done flags somehow.

Comment: To replace the button with text, you can try `event.target.outerHTML = "<span>Done</span>";`, as shown in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Jb6WzPMuYq5I80NP5fIV?p=preview). That change may be quite fragile however.

Answer (score 0):

You should check Renderer2 class, that's the preferred way to solve these kind of tasks.